# React debounce using Lodash

Tags: javascript, react.js, lodash.js

I need people who have experience with React to review my code.

I want to make a debounce using Lodash.

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'
```

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState<string | undefined>(undefined)
const [displayedName, setDisplayedName] = React.useState<string | undefined>(undefined)

const changeName = debounce((e: domProperty) => {
  setName(e.target.value)
}, 1000)

React.useEffect(() => {
  // call API
}, [name])
```

```
return (
  <Input
    placeholder="Player name"
    prefix={<UserOutlined />}
    value={displayedName}
    onChange={(e) => {
      changeName(e);
      setDisplayedName(e.target.value);
    }}
  />
)
```

Is it good? or is there anything wrong there?

So here I use `displayedName` because when I type something in `Input`, the `name` state doesn't change as it might be blocked by a `debounce`.

For example: when I type "alex" at the beginning (it works), then when I want to add the letter "i" (it doesnt, so I can't add or remove any letter it always "alex"), the `name` state is still the same as "alex". Therefore I add `displayedName`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Code you provided can't work properly in some cases. Thing is that `debounce` returns a completely new function with a separate queue on each new render.

   - So, in case if rerender happens, `changeName` will be completely new & will apply changes immediately
   - There is an even worse possibility. As the old debounced function is not destroyed, it can overwrite the value written by the new `changeName`.
   - In order to fix that, you need to wrap it into `React.useMemo`. Like `React.useMemo(debounce(e => { … }, 1000), [])`
2. Consider using a special hook https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/

## useDebounce

I will take code here of useDebounce function from cited article:

```
function useDebounce(value, delay) {
    const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const handler = setTimeout(() => setDebouncedValue(value), delay);

            return () => clearTimeout(handler);
        },
        [value, delay]
    );
    
    return debouncedValue;
}
```

And in your code usage is going to look like:

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
const debouncedName = useDebounce(name, 1000);

const changeName = ((e: domProperty) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    // call API
}, [debouncedName])

return (
    <Input
        placeholder="Player name"
        prefix={<UserOutlined />}
        value={displayedName}
        onChange={(e) => {
            changeName(e);
        }}
    />
)
```

This is more beautiful because you don't need to write the value into two state variables.